# How to emit a @Output event in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

**Angular 2 version used: 2.0.0-alpha.44**

I am trying to emit a Output signal from a component. I followed the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html)
.Below is the code of my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'summary'
})
@View({
    directives: [NgFor, NgIf, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LogoutComponent, BarChartDirective, SunburstChartDirective],
    templateUrl: 'view/summary-component.html'
})
export class SummaryComponent {
    @Output() loadSummary: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    project: Project;
    data: any;

    constructor(public http: Http,
            public router: Router,
            public xxxGlobalService: XXXGlobalService) {
        console.log("SummaryComponent: Created");
        this.getSummary()  
    }

    getSummary() {
        this.project = this.xxxGlobalService.getOpenedProject();
        var url = "/project_summary?username="+ this.xxxGlobalService.getUser().name + "&project_id=" + this.project.id;
        this.http.get(url)
                 .map(res => res.json())
                 .subscribe(
                     data => this.extractData(data),
                     err => this.logError(err),
                () => console.log('SummaryComponent: Successfully got the summary')
        );
    }

    extractData(data) {
        this.data = data;
        console.log("SummaryComponent: Emitting loadSummary event");
        this.loadSummary.next("event");
    }
}
```

However i get error saying "TypeError: router_1.EventEmitter is not a function" when i try to allocate the EventEmitter (below line)

```
@Output() loadSummary: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

I checked the [link](http://victorsavkin.com/post/118372404541/the-core-concepts-of-angular-2) and modified the line to look like

```
@Output() loadSummary: EventEmitter;
```

But the loadSummary seems to be undefined throughout. **How to emit the output signal ? Please help**

Comment: `EventEmitter` must be imported from `angular2/angular2` not from `angular2/router`.

Comment: @EricMartinez. Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: For Angular2 beta 3 use import EventEmitter from 'angular2/core'

Answer (score 4):

As of beta.0 (and maybe earlier), [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) is now in `angular2/core`.

Emit an event using `emit()`:

```
@Output() loadSummary: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
...
this.loadSummary.emit("event");
```

Comment: The emitted event seems to be lost if emitted from the constructor. Apparently the @Output isn't bound until after the constructor.